# how to convert object to collection or list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I save a linq list()/collection result into `HttpContext.Current.Cache` as object, when I try to get object as collection it is null, although `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("data")` is not empty:

```
ICollection<ActionEntity> actions = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("data") as ICollection<ActionEntity>;
```

Comment: Show us the code where you save it.

Comment: @bruno.almeida System.Collections.Generic.List1[<>f__AnonymousType171[Syste‌​m.Collections.Generi‌​c.ICollection`1[Test‌​.Entities.ActionEnti‌​ty]]]

Comment: Have you tried actions.Cast<YourType>().ToList() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try print the type of the data. Something like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(HttpContext.Current.Cache‌​.Get("data").GetType‌​().ToString()).
```

Then cast it with that data type.

You can see the result in windows Output -> Debug.

**EDIT:**

You can not cast an AnonymousType. What you can do is create an object with the same structure of the AnonymousType and use it instead. 
For example, you have a

```
new {  List = new List<ActionEnti‌​ty>() }
```

You can create a `ListOfList<T>` class like this one:

```
class ListOfList<T> { public List<T> List { get; set; } }
```

And instead of using an AnonymousType, use:

```
new ListOfList<ActionEntity> {  List = new List<ActionEnti‌​ty>() }
```

Then you can cast, using this:

```
ListOfList<ActionEntity> data = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("data") as ListOfList<ActionEntity>;
```

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType17`1[System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Test.Entities.ActionEntity]]]

Comment: That means you you a List of an AnonymousType and the anonymous Type has a list on it of List<Test‌​.Entities.ActionEnti‌​ty>. A kind of a List inside a List. You are doing something wrong when writing to HttpContext.Current.Cache. As dotctor asked you, can you show us that code?

Comment: how can I convert the AnonymousType ?

Comment: I think I convert AnonymousType.